# get row associated with the nearest result in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get a recipe scaling method in my app which will return some nicer measurements adapted to the amount the use is serving.

For example, the recipe for 6 people calls for 1 cup of flour. If you scale that for one person, 1/6 a cup of flour is 2.5 tablespoons, which is a nicer way of saying it (why search for and dirty a measuring cup when you can just use a spoon?).

So I have in the db a weights table with weight in grams, corresponding measurement and amount. 
eg. for flour

```
 amount   |   measure   |   grams
----------+-------------+---------
   1      |    cup      |    160
   1      |    tbsp     |     10
   1      |    pound    |    454
```

in my app (using activerecord preferably) I'm trying to get the best fit measurement for each ingredient in the recipe.

```
@ingredients = Recipe.select('food_names.name,
                   ABS(ingredients.grams-weights.grams) as nearest_weight,
                   weights.amount,
                   weights.measure'
               ).joins(
                   {:ingredients=&gt; :food_name},
                   {:food_names=&gt; :weights}
               ).where(
                   "recipes.recipe_id", :recipe_id
               ).order(
                   :nearest_weight
               ).reverse_order
```

the `nearest_weight` searches for the closest match of weights in the database, but I need to find the weight and measure associated with that row, and at the moment, I'm getting all the rows returned.

What I need to do is somehow limit the `nearest_weight` to one row, and then get that row so I know what the weight and measure are, and I'm hoping I can do that all in one query.